# two dimensional array error

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Hi I have just began experiementing with two dimensional arrays. I have constructed the following simple code from my notes but I am get an error that I can't figure out. The "<<" after the cout is underlined. The output is;

'<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion).

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

enum Mines {HIDDEN_MINE, UNCOVERED_MINE, HIDDEN_SAFE, UNCOVERED_SAFE};

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    const string names[] = {"*", "X", "-­‐", "O"};

    cout << names[UNCOVERED_MINE] << endl; //error



system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to `#include <string>`

Answer (score 0):

along with all your included libraries, include string library ,as the << operator is defined under it .By this you will get the build successful .Best of luck...